# Enviar parametro a la URL al cargar la página

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero algo en principio muy sencillo pero no doy con la forma, quiero que cuando se cargue mi index.html se añada un parámetro a la URL y quede tipo index.html?PARAMETRO

¿Como puedo hacerlo?

Completo la información: lo que quiero es añadir a la URL un ID aleatorio cada vez que se cargue la página, tengo el script que genera el parámetro pero no se como añadirlo a la URL al cargar.

Comment: para que quieres el parametro? y si es un parametro fijo porque no agregarlo al inicio de la carga?

Comment: Lo que quiero agregar es un ID automático que se genera al cargar la página, tengo el script que genera el ID automático pero no se como añadirlo a la URL

Comment: podrias hacerlo con js pero se tendria que cargar nuevamente la pagina, lo cual no es muy recomendable, por lo que tambien sugiero que si es un parametro fijo o importante se agrege al inicio de la carga

Comment: puedes agregar que cuando la pagina este cargada la redirijas agregando tu parametro, window.location.replace('misitio.index?parametro1=valorparametro');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende si quieres que se recargue la pagina, te muestros las dos opciones...

1. Recargando la pagina

```
window.location.replace(window.location.href + '?' + PARAMETROS)
```

2. Sin recargar la pagina

```
window.history.replaceState({}, '', window.location.href + '?' + PARAMETROS);
```

Nota: window.location tambien puede usarse sin el prefijo window, osea solo location

Comment: He probado con window.location.replace pero genera una redirección continua, por lo que he probado window.history.replaceState y funciona perfectamente, pero si recargo la URL se va añadiendo el parámetro cada vez, hay alguna forma de que no se añada el parámetro si ya existe?¿

Comment: haz un if con php, obten el valor del parametro que sigue del ? con un $_GET y evalua si ya esta definido

Comment: Nando en ese caso, deberas solo comprobar si existe el parametro en el url.. algo asi:r
```
if (window.location.href.indexOf(PARAMETRO) == -1) {  }
```
dentro del bloque de if colocas el código que te escribí en la solución arriba